# Is absence of If-Match or If-Not-Match header shall be treated as unconditional request?

Tags: http

HTTP 1.1 spec has clear definition of server behavior if one of them is present. In my case, I have two clients, one old and one new. Old client ignores etag in response, and sends put request without etag; new client uses the If-Match + etag in put request. My understanding is that server shall take put request without If-Match as unconditional request and proceed. However, the consequence of it is that without etag, old client might do put request based on old data. So I have the question in Titie, "Is absence of If-Match or If-Not-Match header shall be treated as unconditional request?"

Answer (score 0):

Well. A request is unconditional when it doesn't have any conditions attached to it. The base set of conditional request header fields is defines in http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p4-conditional-25.html, extension specs such as WebDAV add more.

Whether the server actually *accepts* the unconditional request is another story, see http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc6585.html#status-428.